# Transferred domain to new registrar, ordered "id protection", but my info is available in whois

Tags: domain

Situation as per the title. How should I approach this to resolve it, am I wrong in thinking the ID protection should make my info not be visible? It's a .net domain.

Edit - the visible details are only known to the new registrar, not the original one, as it was registered under a different address and not kept up to date. So that record is definitely not a "hangover" from the original registration.

Edit2: contacted the new registrar and it seems that it was a mistake on their side, which they say they have now rectified (waiting on whois servers to update). I just hope no one goes too closely through the "related records" and that I got it changed quickly enough!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't said which service you have registered the domain through so it is difficult to say what their "ID Protection" service is. Assuming that it is the provision of a private registration - then the company you registered through should be the registered owner on the WHOIS directory. As your name is appearing on the WHOIS lookup, it would appear that the registry has made a mistake in their process and not denoted that a private registration has taken place.

This is opinion, but I would contact their customer service and highlight the issue through their channels.

Comment: Exactly, they offer a service whereby "dummy" details (theirs) should appear in place of my personal info, and an email address that redirects to my real one. I didn't "name and shame" as not sure if it's a legal issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't enable privacy when initially registering a domain many Internet services which monitor new domain registration and domain ownership changes will record the original name used when registering the domain and then make that information public via their own sites. Changing the status of your registration ownership to private afterwards won't normally update these third party companies and if anything it will just show the change as an additional record of information in their databases.

Likewise the change made with your domain registrar may take a few days to propagate to the majority of whois servers which return than information when it is searched for publicly.

It's important to understand where the source of the data you are seeing is actually stored (are you using a website or whois server to look this up).

Ultimately some records of the original registration will always be available on-line even if most data sources get updated with the new information over time. The registrar has no control over the 3rd parties.

Useful reference information regarding domain privacy

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_privacy

Comment: Thanks, the address showing is only known to my new registrar (when I registered it initially I used a different address, which was current at the time). The info is only known by the new registrar.

Comment: That does sound like the registrar didn't enable the privacy option on your new registration.